# Execute multiple hive queries using single execute() method of statement class using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am using Java API to access HiveServer2, I have requirement of executing multiple hive queries in single call to *execute()* method of statements class. Is it possible to submit multiple queries of hive in one call to *execute()* method. I have hive properties to set as:

```
SET hive.exec.max.created.files=200000;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; 
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; 
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=5000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=5000; 
              .
              .
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute("SET hive.exec.max.created.files=200000");
              .
              .
```

for that now I am setting these properties one at a time using *execute()* method. Is there any way so i can set all these properties by executing all above statement in one call to *execute()* method.

Expected:

```
stmt.execute("SET hive.exec.max.created.files=200000;
    SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; 
    SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; 
    set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=5000;
    set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=5000;");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is big NO. You cannot execute multiple queries in a single execute() method. Why can't you do the same in a for loop like below

```
String[] queries = new String[] {"SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true", "set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=5000"}; //and so on

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

for(int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++){
   stmt.execute(queries[i]);
}
```

This applies for multiple hive sql queries too like select, insert, delete, etc,. based on the sql statement resultset print or populate in the JTable.

Note : execute(), executeUpdate() and executeQuery() are not the same. Choose based on your sql statement.

> execute() - Returns true if the first object that the query returns is
>   a ResultSet object.
>
> executeUpdate() - Returns an integer representing the number of rows
>   affected by the SQL statement.
>
> executeQuery() - Returns one ResultSet object.

Reference: [docs.oracle.com/javase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html#executing_queries)

HTH